# Is async partial void MyPartialMethod() dangerous?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, async-await

I've seen a lot of warnings about writing code such as...

```
public async void MyDangerousMethodWhichCouldCrashMyApp...
```

I've read that its OK with Eventhandlers as they must return void.  However [partial methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6b0scde8.aspx) must also return void.   You can have the following code...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    MainAsync().Wait();
    Console.ReadLine();
}

async static Task MainAsync()
{
    MyCodeGeneratedClass c = new MyCodeGeneratedClass();
    try
    {
        await c.MyCodeGeneratedMethod();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
    }
}

public partial class MyCodeGeneratedClass
{
    public async Task MyCodeGeneratedMethod()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"));
        MyCustomCode();
    }

    partial void MyCustomCode();
}
```

and then implement as...

```
partial class MyCodeGeneratedClass
{
    async partial void MyCustomCode()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"));
        throw new Exception("Boom");
    }
}
```

But what will happen to the application if the implementation of MyCustomCode encounters an exception?

If it's a no go, given how prevalent async / await is, does that mean partial methods are essentially obsolete?  Should code generation systems stop exposing partial methods in favour of events or perhaps better still empty protected virtual methods in a base class? i.e.

```
protected virtual Task MyCustomCode(T foo)
{
    return Task.FromResult(0);
}
```

EDIT: OK so I've made several updates to the code.  After the original pseudo code I wrote didn't get well received.  The code above I think demonstrates that there's definitely an issue with async partial void MyPartialMethod as the call to MyCodeGeneratedMethod does seem to bring down the app domain, despite the try catch around the call.  I'm just wondering if there are better options than moving to protected virtual base class methods.

Comment: I'm afraid your question is very unclear. Please consider including more context of what is your issue and what you wish to achieve.

Comment: OK... so i've elaborated the code for readers who've never used code generation, partial classes or partial methods.

Comment: I don't use partial methods, and I understood the original question perfectly (although `async partial void MyPartialMethod();` in the original doesn't compile since the async keyword can only appear on a method with a body).

Comment: Yea sorry the original code was wrong....

Comment: I would assume the method would behave exactly the same as any other async void method in terms of exceptions. As to whether partial methods are obsolete, I can't comment since I don't use them, but if you're replacing them with virtual methods those methods should be `virtual Task` (i.e. not async) and return Task.CompletedTask (if they must be virtual and cannot be abstract). But that's just a nitpick on my part.

Comment: I've added a post on MS user voice for this...

https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15954217-exceptions-within-async-partial-void-method-caus

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> But what will happen to the application if the implementation of MyCustomCode encounters an exception?

The semantics for `async void` methods are that exceptions are raised directly on the `SynchronizationContext` that was current at the beginning of the method. This and other fun facts about `async void` are covered in my [`async` best practices](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/jj991977.aspx) article.

> does that mean partial methods are essentially obsolete?

Equally as obsolete as event handlers. So, no, not really. However, they weren't updated to allow a return type of `Task`, so it seems like they're a language feature that isn't being actively updated with the rest of the language.

> Should code generation systems stop exposing partial methods in favour of events or perhaps better still empty protected virtual methods in a base class?

Events wouldn't change this at all; they'd still be implemented with `async void`.

If a "hook" needs to be asynchronous, then that changes all the generated code, since it must also all be asynchronous.

An async partial method would only not work if the generated code needed some result from that partial method *and* the implementation had to do some asynchronous work in order to generate that result. In my experience, partial methods are conceptually more like events, so `async void` would be acceptable.

Comment: In the case of events and partial methods do you think it's advisable/appropriate to wrap async code in a try/catch as I've depicted in the answer I posted below?

Comment: @Mick: Yes, I do.

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be a big issue for people working with Xamarin which generates code with a lot of hooks implemented as partial methods as can be seen in this thread...

https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/2766/cannot-await-in-an-async-partial-method

As I posted there, I would recommend to anyone that is thinking about writing async code within a partial method to wrap their async code within a try catch as follows...

```
public partial class MyCodeGeneratedClass
{
    public async Task MyCodeGeneratedMethod()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"));
        MyCustomCode();
    }

    partial void MyCustomCode();
}

partial class MyCodeGeneratedClass
{
    async partial void MyCustomCode()
    {
        try
        {
            await MyCustomCodeAsync();
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    protected async Task MyCustomCodeAsync()
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        Console.WriteLine(await client.GetStringAsync("http://msdn.microsoft.com"));

        throw new Exception("Boom");
    }
}
```

Trying and catching around the async Task method should protect the app domain.  Also, if/when Microsoft [improve partial methods](https://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio-2015/suggestions/15954217-exceptions-within-async-partial-void-method-caus) it might also make it easier to refactor your code.

As I have control over the scripts which generate the code in my project, I've chosen not to expose partial methods in situations where it's likely there'll be I/O and async is desirable and instead provide empty protected virtual Task methods in the base class. Also the generated code needs to be able to await the CustomCode method, there seems to be no way of doing that with async partial methods.